# difference between present and present perfect

Tags: past-tense

SB: Kiam, you're a workhorse. I eat breakfast at 9:00, and you've already put in two hours of work.
KL: Oh, I'**ve had** breakfast at 9:00. But it was always because I got so absorbed in my work I forgot to eat.

In this case could KL have answered  "Oh, I have breakfast at 9.00"as it seems to be a habit .In term of meaning what does bring the use of present perfect(up to now I have taken breakfast at 9  but  that habit can change)

Answer (score 1):

I think KL means "I've **sometimes** had breakfast at 9.00, but only when I got so absorbed..."

He's not using the Present Perfect to mean "up to now" but, as defined [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect), "for something that happened in the past but is important in the present."
The speaker would stress the word "had": "I've **had** breakfast at 9.00..."

If he wanted to say he *habitually* had breakfast at 9.00 he would say, "Oh, **I** have breakfast at 9.00", as you suggest, and would stress the "I".

Comment: I think I don't get the difference between both versions   Btw I thought that "sometimes" was followed by  present not  present perfect .Does present perfect  mean it is not a "regular" thing and has only happened in a very few cases. In this example it means that KL did not take it because he was so absorbed ; he is talking only about today in the second part of the sentence

Comment: 'Sometimes' is an adverb. Adverbs have no effect on the tense. These are all good: I had sometimes eaten, I have sometimes eaten, I sometimes ate, I was sometimes eating, I sometimes eat, I will sometimes eat...  Please visit the link in my last message and read the whole page. It explains the different uses of the present perfect. And please read my answer.  KL has sometimes had breakfast at 9.00.

Comment: yes he has sometimes  had breakfast at 9 but not today

Comment: That's right. Exactly.

Comment: And he seems to be saying he sometimes forgets to eat _earlier_ than 9.00. So then he _has_ to eat at 9.00. I think he makes SB feel very lazy!